# Why setprojectdir command is not found in virtualenvwrapper while other command work fine

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I install Python2.7.11 In CentOS 7 with this command

```
make altinstall
```

and use

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 VirtualEnvName
```

to create a new virtualenv.

But when workon this virtualenv, I want to set the project dir with the command:

```
setprojectdir PATH_TO_PROJECT
```

and this error show up:

```
-bash: setprojectdir: command not found
```

while command like "lssitepackages" work just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, that should be `setvirtualenvproject` with no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out, I have to use

```
setvirtualenvproject
```

to set project instend of use

```
setprojectdir
```

Comment: It seems that `setvirtualenvproject` is a valid command of `virtualenvwrapper` which is for MacOS/Linux, while `setprojectdir` is valid of `virtualenvwrapper-win` for Windows.